# Use lapply to concatenate list elements

Tags: r, lapply

The issue follows below. First a working example:

```
library(stringr)
library(rebus)

phone_numbers_mat <- structure(c("555-555-0191", NA, "555) 555 0191", "555.555.0191", 
"555", NA, "555", "555", "555", NA, "555", "555", "0191", NA, 
"0191", "0191"), .Dim = c(4L, 4L)
```

The following code re-constructs the phone numbers from the matrix above:

```
str_c(
  "(",
  phone_numbers_mat[,2],
  ")",
  " ",
  phone_numbers_mat[,3],
  "-",
  phone_numbers_mat[,4] )
```

And returns this result:

```
[1] "(555) 555-0191" NA               "(555) 555-0191" "(555) 555-0191"
```

But when I try do a similar operation with a list structure, I get the error **"Error: incorrect number of dimensions"**.

```
phone_numbers_list <- list(structure(c("555-555-0191", "555", "555", "0191"), .Dim = c(1L, 
4L)), structure(character(0), .Dim = c(0L, 4L)), structure(c("555) 555 0191", 
"555", "555", "0191"), .Dim = c(1L, 4L)), structure(c("555.555.0191", 
"555.555.0192", "555", "555", "555", "555", "0191", "0192"), .Dim = c(2L, 
4L)))
```

My attempt (returns error above):

```
lapply( phone_numbers_list,
str_c(
  "(",
  phone_numbers[,2],
  ")",
  " ",
  phone_numbers[,3],
  "-",
  phone_numbers[,4])
  )
```

**How can I correctly process the list to re-construct the phone numbers?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need an anonymous function call

```
lapply(phone_numbers_list, function(phone_numbers) str_c(
   "(",
   phone_numbers[,2],
    ")",
    " ",
   phone_numbers[,3],
    "-",
   phone_numbers[,4])
  )
#[[1]]
#[1] "(555) 555-0191"

#[[2]]
#[1] "() -"

#[[3]]
#[1] "(555) 555-0191"

#[[4]]
#[1] "(555) 555-0191" "(555) 555-0192"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! By the way, does `lapply` have an option to skip over empty list items? The second list item in `phone_numbers` is empty. I've solved the issue with pre-processing for now: `phone_numbers_list <- phone_numbers_list[lapply(phone_numbers_list,length)>0]`

Comment: @Bobby You can use `Filter` i.e. `Filter(length, phone_numbers_list)`

Comment: I don't completely understand `Filter`. Maybe it would help me to also know how I would use it to get list elements with length greater than 1.

Comment: @Bobby It will filter the length of list elements that are not 0.  Or create a logical expression with `lengths` `lengths(phone_numbers_list)>0`